# In iPhone, where does save a file downloaded from a iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios

From my app, I can download a zip file from a server through NSURLConnection. While I'm downloading I'm writing to this into a file, so that it will save into documentsDirectory.

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
currentDownload = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Zipfile"];
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:currentDownload];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:data];
[fileHandle closeFile];
```

This is the code I used for downloading and its working. If I run the app in simulator, I can see the downloaded file in MAC in the folder /Users/TECSOLiMac02/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/9DECB1F4-C88D-4B62-BA1F-B9D5D4E421B9/Documents/Zipfile

Where can I see this downloaded file in iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every application is sandboxed in iPhone.Each application have it's on directory structure in device (like in simulator).

The path of document directory in mobile is something like:

**/var/mobile/Applications/AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEFFFFFF/Documents/**

The files in that directories cannot be accesses by any other applications. It can be accessed by the owner application itself. And can be accessed through code.

If you want to see the files in document directory you need to set the `UIFileSharingEnabled`  key in the info.plist

[image: info.plist]

The files in the application's document directory will be displayed on the itunes as like:

[image: File Sharing]
Please check the **[tutorial](http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/category/uifilesharingenabled)** for details.

Comment: Or if you do not want the `iTunes file share` option you can use Xcode  to get the files from/to your device to check them: http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/retrieving-files-for-document-directory/

Comment: @rckoenes:  It is a new information for me. thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: Yes I want to see the file and I set the UIFileSharingEnabled key in info.plist 
What is the location of downloded file in iPhone now?

Comment: @NoufalKmc: it'll be inside the document directory.

Comment: Is there any way to see the file from iPhone/iPad itself without connecting to the desktop?

Comment: @ Midhun M : You mean there is a dirctory called document in iPhone/iPad ?

Comment: @NoufalKmc: check the bold in above answer, the application path will look like `var/mobile/Applications/AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEFFFFFF/` the AAAAAA-BBBB-CCC-DDD-EEFFF will change for each app. And there will be three folder for each app document,library and temp inside the folder

Comment: @ Midhun M : I think to see this directory, we have to jailbreak the iPhone. Or any other way or any third party app for browsin this file?

Comment: @NoufalKmc: one application cannot access other app's datas and folders. If you need this you want to jailbreak your device

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see this files in iPhone/iPad you have to allow (set to YES) "Application supports iTunes file sharing" in the project Info.

Comment: Is there any way to see the file from iPhone/iPad itself without connecting to the desktop?

Comment: If you need this for debug only you can browse and print (via NSLog()) the content of the document directory (of your own app).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, after downloading the file, go to the settings of the same app and enable file sharing. Then click on the file and click on `save to camera roll`, That's all.