# Where to store downloaded data in iPhone application?

Tags: ios

I have a scenario in my application that I need to download mp3, pdf, text files using my application.

How can I download, and where to store, data using my application?

Comment: inside `NSDocumentDirectory`!

Comment: Hi may be you can use [this][1] link 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987788/in-iphone-where-does-save-a-file-downloaded-from-a-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.somewhere.com/thefile.png";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
 NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
 NSArray*paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

 NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];
 [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

You can store in Document directory,Below is example to store a image  .Below is link explained to store audio video file

[How to download audio/video files from internet and store in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245345/how-to-download-audio-video-files-from-internet-and-store-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

Document Directory is best to store data.

```
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path 
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.txt"];
[sampleText writeToFile:path atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this... It depends on what data to store. Apple rejected me Apps several times for storing images (probably too much)  in Doc folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what will you need to do with data. If data can be recreated or downloaded, save it in temp o cacje directory. If data is created by user and have to be backed up, you can use Documents to sync with iCloud.
I recommend you to read Apple documentation because if you this wrong way, your App could be rejected.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

You can exclude your files to be backed up (and stored in Documents folder)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html